# Spring boot @Transactional doesn't rollback

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using Spring boot application, on that i am trying to achieve Transactional management. But Spring doesn't rollback the data which saved in same method.

Code base: https://github.com/vinothr/spring-boot-transactional-example

Can any one help me?

This is my repository class for 'Test' entity.

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<com.example.demo.Test, Long> {

}
```

I have created one end-point which used to save the data to 'Test' entity. After save happen, I thrown RunTimeException, but it is not rollbacking the saved value

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@Transactional
public void create() {
    System.out.println("test");
    final Test p = createTest();
    testRepository.save(p);

    final Test p1 = createTest();
    testRepository.save(p1);
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: Add additional code to your question don't link to your repository and expect a full code review to happen.

Comment: @m-deinum Sure. Please see the latest

Comment: Are transactions enabled on your MySQL? InnoDB does not support transactions, you need to use MyISAM.

Comment: @PouriyaZarbafian Hey Thanks. 'InnoDB' suppports Transactional but 'MyISAM' doesn't.

Comment: @PouriyaZarbafian I am using MyISAM, After I changed to innodb it worked Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @VinothRajendran if you have solved your issue, feel free to make your own answer and accept it in order to close the loop on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine after I changed into 'InnoDB' engine because I was using 'MyISAM' engine which doesn't support transaction.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try indicate `@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)`

Comment: The problem is the engine of the database. I was using 'MyISAM' as engine which doesn't supports Transactional