# Spring Boot @Transactional annotation doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

My signupUser method saves a user and sends an email to the registered email address. If the email fails to be sent, the user data saved has to be rolled back. I've added `@Transactional` on the signupUser method but it doesn't roll back when an exception happens and the data gets permanently saved. I temporarily replaced the sending email part with simply `throw RunTimeException` to check if transactional would work but the result was the same (didn't roll back).

This method is called in a `@Controller` annotated class.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Service
public class AuthService {

        private UserRepository userRepository;
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthService.class);
        private CustomMailSender mailSender;
        private ModelMapper modelMapper;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Autowired
        public AuthService(UserRepository userRepository, CustomMailSender mailSender, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.mailSender= mailSender;
            this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        }

 
    @Transactional
      public void signupUser(SignUpForm signUpForm){
        userRepository.save(new User(signUpForm.getUsername(), passwordEncoder.encode(signUpForm.getPassword()), signUpForm.getEmail()));
        throw new RuntimeException("腹たつ");

        }
```

Comment: Can you share the import details of @Transactional ?, i.e. from which dependency it is been used. (import path)

Comment: This is what I have: `import javax.transaction.Transactional;`

Comment: This should actually work, can u share the project in some remote location like github repo ?

Comment: Have you tried: ``@Transactional(rollbackOn={Exception.class})``

Comment: @JRK I did but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Nakul Goyal Here's my github repo: (https://github.com/yuppi0809omg/stock_check_api) Sorry my project and code is such a mess...>< and thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yuka I think that you should use import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional instead to use Spring transaction management (not java transactions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it was the configuration on mySQL. I changed the engine from the default one to InnoDB and it worked!

[Spring boot @Transactional doesn't rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582919/spring-boot-transactional-doesnt-rollback?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, IMO you should use `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;` bcuz you're using spring, not EE

Answer (score 0):

If the annotation did not work you can try an alternative way for the same, modify your service class like the below code

```
public void signupUser(SignUpForm signUpForm){
        userRepository.add(signUpForm.getUsername(), passwordEncoder.encode(signUpForm.getPassword()), signUpForm.getEmail());
        throw new RuntimeException("腹たつ");

        }
```

Add the below code into Repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value="insert into..... ?1 ?2 ?3",nativeQuery=true)
void add(name,password,email);
```

so from your service just call the method add passing 3 parameters and here ?1, ?2 will be replaced with name password etc.. try with this and it will work